# PHP: foreach not forming an array

Tags: php, xml, arrays, rss, foreach

I do this and it works.

```
<?php
    function load_file($url) 
    {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch));
        return $xml;
    }

    $feedurl = 'http://www.astrology.com/horoscopes/daily-extended.rss';
    $rss = load_file($feedurl);

    $items = array();
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($rss->channel->item->description as $i => $description) 
    {
        $items[$count++] = $description;
    }
    echo $items[0];
?>
```

When I `echo $items[1];`  it doesn't show the next one in line. Not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: how many items are there in $rss->channel->item->description (associative) array?

Comment: `var_dump($items)` see what it returns. And what is the xml format ?

Comment: there are 12 <items>s and inside each <item> there is one <description>

Comment: Seems like foreach just loops one time. My guess is to iterate `$rss->channel->item` instead

Comment: it's an rss feed. sorry taking so long to respond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of your xml:

```
<channel>
    <item>
        <description>blah</description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <description>blah1</description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <description>blah2</description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <description>blah3</description>
    </item>
</channel>
```

When you do `$rss->channel->item->description` you're getting the first `item`'s `description`.

You need to first loop through the `items` and then get each description.

e.g.:

```
$descriptions = array();
foreach($rss->channel->item as $item){
    $descriptions[] = $item->description;
    // note I don't need the $count variable... if you just use
    // [] then it auto increments the array count for you.
}
```

Hope that helps. Its untested, but should work.

Comment: this makes sense, trying this now.

Comment: you're the man, this worked, it won't let me accept your answer for 4 more minutes, I appreciate it your time, I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me!